# How to change keyboard character in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

How to change the letter e with ę in Ubuntu xkb. my language doesn't use e,  instead we used ę.  The character e is not used at all.  the keyboard layout that I am using is us

Comment: Why continue to use the "US" keyboard layout? Why not configure it for your language?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+U+0119
 will do it.

If you don't like to change your keyboard layout to your language as waltinator mentioned before, you might have a look on various websites about
UTF / UTF8 / UTF16 key codes if you often do need some which do not usually come with the US keyboard layout …

For example, I found the code for "your" ę on

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=dec